# Why is condition with `cout` evaluated to true?

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements, cout

Why *if* statement with condition `cout << c << endl` is evaluated to true.

The below code runs without showing the error. I can not understand why does it happen.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int c = 0;
    if (cout << c << endl) {
        c++;
    }
    cout << c <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Also, why don't I need semicolon there?

Comment: What does the question title have to do with the question body? What are you asking?

Answer (score 4):

`std::cout` doesn't return `true`. It's the overloaded [`operator bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)  of the returned `iostream` which is `cout` here.

the bool operator returns `true` unless the last taken is `eof` or the operation has caused a `fail` or `bad` state.

Now, why don't you need the semicolon? because it's an expression not a statement.

Like when you use

```
while(true)// you don't write while(true;)
```

Comment: in other words it returns true is nothing went wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << c << endl
```

is an *expression*. If you add a `;` at the end, the *expression* becomes a *statement*.

The grammar for `if` statements is that the code inside the `()` is an *expression*. This expression still gets executed, and there is no error here. The result of evaluating this expression is just  `cout`, which gets contextually converted to boolean `true` inside the `if` condition (since the `cout` expression is successful), and so `c` is incremented.

Outside of an `if` statement, the expression is not valid (or rather, it is not a statement yet), so it must be made into a statement for it to be executed.